# bash -> delete tableData lines that have no visble html content

Tags: html, awk, sed, grep

I have a table.html file which contains a large table with a lot of inline style

The file is formatted that a tableData tag is in one line.
Here is a short example:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr style="height: 17px;">
    <td style="width: 120.078px; height: 17px;" align="RIGHT" valign="TOP"><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;"><strong>CEO </strong></span></td>
    <td style="width: 438.922px; height: 49px;" rowspan="2" align="LEFT" valign="TOP"><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;"><strong> Name<br/></strong> E-Mail<br/></span></td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 32px;">
    <td style="width: 120.078px; height: 32px;" align="RIGHT" valign="TOP"><span style="font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt;"> </span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

The file is huge and  I want to delete every line that is a `<td> </td>` line and has no content (whitepaces counts also as no content)

I tried to use awk but my knowledge is not enough
In this short example the output after the delete would look like this:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr style="height: 17px;">
    <td style="width: 120.078px; height: 17px;" align="RIGHT" valign="TOP"><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;"><strong>CEO </strong></span></td>
    <td style="width: 438.922px; height: 49px;" rowspan="2" align="LEFT" valign="TOP"><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;"><strong> Name<br/></strong> E-Mail<br/></span></td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 32px;">
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E '/\<td\>/{\~(<[^>]*>)+ *[[:alpha:]] *~!d}' input_file
<table>
<tbody>
<tr style="height: 17px;">
    <td style="width: 120.078px; height: 17px;" align="RIGHT" valign="TOP"><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;"><strong>CEO </strong></span></td>
    <td style="width: 438.922px; height: 49px;" rowspan="2" align="LEFT" valign="TOP"><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;"><strong> Name<br/></strong> E-Mail<br/></span></td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 32px;">
</tr>
</tbody>
```